# Show that $(z, w)$ is linearly dependent iff the imaginary part of $z\bar{w}$ is 0.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, vector-spaces, complex-numbers

Consider $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. If $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$, show that $(z, w)$ is linearly dependent iff the imaginary part of $z\bar{w}$ is 0.

I'm just unsure about the question and how to approach it.

What it "$\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}$-vector space" means and what it is we are trying to prove.

Could someone explain this to me, and point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb C$ as $\mathbb R$-vector space means, that the scalars of our vector space are real numbers. For example, linear independence of $z,w \in \mathbb C$ (the complex numbers are our vectors) means

> If $\alpha z + \beta w = 0$ for real numbers $\alpha, \beta$, then $\alpha = \beta = 0$.

For example, $1$ and $i$ are $\mathbb R$-linear indepedent, as $\alpha + \beta i = 0$ holds only for $\alpha = \beta = 0$.

This changes, if we consider $\mathbb C$ as $\mathbb C$-vector space, now the scalars $\alpha, \beta$ are allowed to be complex, and in this case $1$ and $i$ are dependent, as $\alpha + \beta i = 0$ for $\alpha = -i$ and $\beta = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The complex numbers can be represented as $z=a+ib$ with real numbers $a,b$. The real numbers are considered as the "components" of the 2-dimensional vector (with the real part as the x-component and the imaginary part as y-component).

Now, $z,w$ are two different complex numbers. Let $\alpha z + \beta w = 0$ for some Parameters $\alpha, \beta$. The complex numbers are linear Independent if and only if this equation can be solved for $\alpha=\beta=0$. General solution of this equation:

$\beta = - \frac{\alpha z}{w}$; Multiplying with $\bar{w}$:

$\beta = - \frac{\alpha z \bar{w}}{w \bar{w}}$; By condition and $w \bar{w}$ is real number it follows that $\frac{\beta}{\alpha} \in R$.

Therefore $z = - \frac{\beta}{\alpha}w$, i.e. $w$ is only a multiple of $z$. Therefore the condition for being linear Independent reduces to $\alpha (\frac{\beta}{\alpha} w+z) = 0$ which can be satisfied if and only if it is set $\alpha = 0$.